# How to use two constructors in the same 2D array? Java

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I have two constructors I want to use in order to differentiate two types of objects in the same array, though the "Type is mismatched". So I know I have to declare the array differently, I'm just not sure what to do.

For the first three places in the array I want to use the Pilots class, and for the others the Passenger class.

```java
public class Project_Space
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
// 2D Array of Passengers objects- the Passengers class is in the Passengers.java file
//Pilot objects are constructed from Pilots.java file

Passengers[][] Members ;

  int num_flights= 6;  //create the "x" bound/size of the array

  int num_passengers= 9;     //create the "y" bound/size of the array

  Members = new Passengers[num_flights][num_passengers]; //define the size of the array 6flights/9Passengers

  //The Members array at index 0 is the first flight

//Members[0][0] = new Pilots(1,-1,"","","",0);  //This spot in the array is for the Flight number in the first spot. Everything else are place holders for data that doesn't pertain to the company

Members[0][1] = new Pilots(1,"1877963200","Amadeus","Durrutti","Buckminster Cornwallis","1288211435", 11);  //This spot in the array is for the first passenger of flight #1

Members[0][2] = new Pilots(2,"6054350085","Sirius","Sassafrass","Ali Bababa","1776812631", 9);

Members[0][3] = new Passengers(1,"7065253333","Amy","Hartman","Betty Sue","7708889999", 3, 50000,"0554055405540554");

Members[0][4] = new Passengers(2,"7545251337","Amanda","Zion","Beatrice Twix","7448656577", 4, 2000,"0554055405541111");

Members[0][5] = new Passengers(3,"8904448899","Janet","Graves","Neal Wade","4445556666", 5, 3000, "9031029266161432");

Members[0][6] = new Passengers(4,"8902234567","Kristen","Pickering","Christopher Soto","5685461208", 6, 51500, "0985028135114275");

Members[0][7] = new Passengers(5,"5000893778","Julianna","Estrada","Jill Hansen","2770779833", 7, 0, "0213595590286251");

Members[0][8] = new Passengers(6,"2080670437","Regena","Mckenzie","Vicki Cook","6224215759", 8, 250, "8204699533830238");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice example of OOP.

If Pilots and Passengers are both sub-classes of the same base class, this will work fine. For instance, both classes may contain similar fields, like name and id.

Declare the base class Person with those fields and any other common methods that both classes contain. Then you will be able to declare the array as `Person[][] Members;`

```
public class Person {

  String firstName,lastName;
  int id;

  //constructors, getter and setter methods

}
```

Then Passenger and Pilot can both inherit from Person like this:

```
public class Pilot extends Person {
    int totalHoursLogged;
    String airline;
    int salary;

    //constructors and methods that differentiate Pilots from Passengers.

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation, I will implement it and let you know how it goes once I get back to my computer. I'll also upvote you once I get the rep. Thanks again bud.

Comment: Is this a project for a programming class?  Happy coding :)

Comment: Yes it is for a programming class. Your explanation was perfect, just took me a little to adapt everything. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of `Object` class or define a parent class for `Pilots` and `Passengers` and then create an array of your superclass. You will be able to add any child class objects to parent class array.

Comment: Thank you, I knew I was close I just couldn't find any examples! =] As soon as I get to where I can upvote you got it.